# New transaction for partial import of data in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I need process and then save multiple records of 2 flows. First flow define objects itself, and second flow defines some additional attributes of that object. For demonstration I use `Foo` object, with `barCode` which represent additional attribute.

```
public class Foo {
    private Long id;
    private Integer fooCode;
    private Integer barCode;
}
```

import service looks like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void importAll() {
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> map = Map.of(
        111, 100,
        222, 200,
        333, 300,
        444, 400,
        555, 500);

    map.forEach((fooCode, barCode) -> {
        try {
            nestedImport(fooCode, barCode);
        } catch (Error e) {
            log.error("Something wrong", e);
        }
    });
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void nestedImport(Integer fooCode, Integer barCode) {
    fooService.createFoo(fooCode);
    fooBarService.setFooBarCombination(fooCode, barCode);
}
```

For this simplified version I use map, which contains foo code as key, and bar code as value. For each iteration I pass these values into another method which is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to create new transaction. If foo or combination of foo and bar failed, I want skip this record and continue to next. To simulate runtime error I implement this method for saving foo:

```
@Override
public void createFoo(Integer fooCode) {
    if (fooCode % 2 == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error code!");
    }
    fooRepository.save(new Foo(fooCode));
}
```

I expected that import will save foo records with codes 111, 333, and 555 but after first exception whole process finishes and nothing save in database. I also added try catch for "dangerous" method but this haven't affect. Exception was handled, but process still ends. Can you tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: If you are calling a transactional method from the same bean, @Transactional has no affect. You can move nestedImport into a different bean.

Comment: @Serge thank you it helps. And rest of Transactional annotations are ok?

Comment: Depending on what else is in the method, importAll() may not need @Transactional (then to be removed, to avoid needless creation of a transaction if none exists, triggered by default Propagation.REQUIRED).